# Can I add Faces from an array to a THREE.BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, mesh, buffer-geometry

I will create a Mesh which is based on a BufferGeometry.
At the moment I have a worker which is responsible for my geometry.

**Worker:**
First of all I create a Three.Geometry. Then I build my bufferGeometry and send data back to main-thread.

1.) I convert my geometry into a `THREE.BufferGeometry`

```
var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry ( geometry );
```

2.) Next I get the BufferAttributes

```
var attributePosition = bufferGeometry.getAttribute(name);//name = position, color, normal)
```

3.) Next I create a bufferArray

```
bufferArrayPosition.push(attributePosition);
```

4.) At the end I send these array back to the main thread

```
postMessage([bufferArrayColor, bufferArrayNormal, bufferArrayPosition]);
```

**Main-Thread:**
In the main-thread I rebuild my bufferGeometry and convert this to a THREE.Geometry

```
 //receive messages from web worker
    worker.onmessage = function (e) {
        alert(e.data);

        var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        for (var i = 0; i < e.data[0].length; i ++){
            bufferGeometry.addAttribute('color', e.data[0][i].array, 3); 
            bufferGeometry.addAttribute('normal', e.data[1][i].array, 3);
            bufferGeometry.addAttribute('position', e.data[2][i].array, 3);

            var t = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(bufferGeometry);
            material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            mesh.push(new THREE.Mesh(t, material));
            Scene.scene.add(mesh[i]);
        }

    };
```

At the end the triangulate faces are lost!!! I have only standard face indices (0,1,2) (3,4,5), ...
Actually I am doing some triangulation in the worker thread. These faces are still existing in the THREE.Geometry before the conversion to a bufferGeometry (step 1).

How can I add these faces to the bufferGeometry?

Comment: Your 3rd step is not correct if you ask me...

Comment: Sorry you are right ...

Comment: Is it not simply `bufferArrayPosition = attributePosition.array`?

Comment: Yes I already predefined my bufferArrayPosition as an array at the beginning

Comment: @Moehre Why are you converting from `BufferGeometry` to `Geometry` before adding to the scene?

Comment: Because for each polygon I will add further information (building_nr. and surface_type). So at the end with the origin geometry I have an array will all polygons as seperate geometry which are including further information. I think to handle this in bufferGeometry is not so easy. Because than I have instead an array with all mesh objects only one buffergeometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of buffer geometries:

- **indexed:**

  *In indexed buffer geometries the positions are stored in the `position` buffer attribute and indexes are stored in the `index` buffer attribute. Positions can be reused in a indexed buffer geometry.*
- **non-indexed (also known as triangle soup)**

  *In a non-indexed array there is no index attribute all positions are stored in the position buffer attribute and every three subsequent points in the `position` attribute form one single triangle.*

In case your original buffer geometry is indexed you will have to make sure your triangle definitions (so the index array from the `index` attribute) is also sent back to your main thread and used to recreate the buffer geometry.

You can get it from the buffer geometry using [the `getIndex` method](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L31) like this:

```
indexAttribute = bufferGeometry.getIndex();
```

### UPDATE

[Here a fiddle that demonstrates geometry vs buffer geometry](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/7kqu1697/4/) for a simple square.

```
// What you need to send to main thread from your worker:
positions = bufferGeometry.attributes['position'].array;
indices = bufferGeometry.index.array;
```

Comment: In my case I have a **non-indexed buffer geometry**. After the method `var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry ( geometry );` my index attribute is null. Does it normally happen after this conversion that index attribute is null? Do I have to rebuild the index attribute manually after this conversion?

Comment: @Moehre Check [here in this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6926); Apparently that is normal behavior for this method. Not sure what is best way to deal with it in your case. Since you get what you referred to as *standard indices* the geometry should look fine, or are you missing faces?

Comment: No it doesn´t look fine for my geometry. Actually I am using earcut interpolation and it is important for me to use these face indices.

Comment: @Moehre **[Here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/7kqu1697/4/)** where you can see an example on how to create the same geometry with `THREE.Geometry` vs `THREE.BufferGeometry`. You could use this example to create your indexed buffer geometry (attributes) directly from your triangulation result.